# in NEFilterDataProvider want to show custom block page on .drop() method

Tags: swift, vpn, firewall, networkextension

working with NetworkExtension and managed to block the urls. further, I want to show custom block page on the class `NEFilterDataProvider` method `handleNewFlow`.

I managed to block the urls. now I want to show custom page on .drop()